# How to display a dynamically created DIV next to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net, css

I am creating a page that will display log files on a page dynamically as they are created. Here is my front end:

```
                <div id="container">
                <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server"     ID="ServerUpdates"> 
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#container {
width:100%;
display: inline-block;
height:100%;
}

.textboxStatus
{
 /*background-image:url('http://placehold.it/15/15');*/
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
/* background-position:3px 3px;*/
 border:solid 1px black;
 padding:20px;
 width:600px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 clear:left;
 /*position:relative;*/
}
/*.textbox input
{
 border:none;
 background:transparent;
 width:100%;     
 outline: none;
}*/
.textboxURL
{
 /*background-image:url('http://placehold.it/15/15');*/
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
/* background-position:3px 3px;*/
 border:solid 1px black;
 padding:20px;
 width:575px;
 height:475px;
 float:right;
 /*clear: right;
 position:relative;*/
 display:inline;
}
```

Here is my code behind:

```
        protected void CreateDiv(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"\\server\d$\websites\Updates\Product\Production\Logs";
        //int rowCount = 0;

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        List<FileInfo> FileList = dir.GetFiles().ToList();
        ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<asp:GridView runat='server' ID='Grid' AutoGenerateColumns='false'>"));
        ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<Columns>"));

        foreach (FileInfo file in FileList)
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));

            // string[] findStatus = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path, "codepush.log.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            // string[] findURL = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "sql.output.log.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            bool findStatus = (file.Name.Contains("codepush.log.")) ? true : false;//File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, ".txt"));
            bool findURL = (file.Name.Contains("sql.output.")) ? true : false;

            if (findStatus == true)
            {
                //ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<br /><div class=\"statusLog\"><asp:TextBox runat=\"server\" id=\"tbStatus{0}\"/> </div><div class=\"urlLog\"></div>", count)));
                //(TextBox)ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("tbStatus" + count.ToString());
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<asp:BoundField Datafield={0} /><div class='textboxStatus'>", rowCount)));
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                txt.Wrap = false;
                txt.Width = 600;
                txt.Height = 500;

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    txt.Text = txt.Text + sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
                //Panel txt = new Panel();
                //txt.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
                //txt.Wrap = true;
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(txt);
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</Columns>"));
            }

            if (findURL == true)
            {
                //ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<br /><div class=\"statusLog\"><asp:TextBox runat=\"server\" id=\"tbStatus{0}\"/> </div><div class=\"urlLog\"></div>", count)));
                //(TextBox)ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("tbStatus" + count.ToString());
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<Columns>"));
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<asp:BoundField Datafield={0} /><div class='textboxURL'>", rowCount)));
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                txt.Wrap = false;
                txt.Width = 575;
                txt.Height = 475;

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    txt.Text = txt.Text + sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
                //Panel txt = new Panel();
                //txt.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
                //txt.Wrap = true;
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(txt);
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</Columns>"));
           }
            //rowCount++;
        }
        ServerUpdates.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</asp:GridView>"));
    }
```

My issue is that it is not displaying the URL div next to the first Status div and so fourth. The URL div displays last.

I need it to display the URL div next to the Status div for each div (file).

I have been trying GridView so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please clarify your markup section with more detail (e.g. elements that match your css classes); your code-behind is un-necessary in this case.

Comment: How about you read everything first. K thanks :)

Comment: You have a display issue, correct? What is required (for me) to directly answer your specific question is your markup and your css. Your css looks complete, but your markup is not. (e.g. where are your textboxStatus and textboxURL elements in your markup)? This is probably a very simple fix as those who have answered have noted, but I choose to wait for all the facts man!

Comment: If you read the code behind you'd see that I am adding the HTML elements to the update panel. The facts are there bro!

Comment: I get it, but you are asking us to spend time figuring out your code behind, when the final rendering against your css is what is going to solve your problem. Sorry, I do this for free. If you don't want to provide the actual markup, that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the problem, but to your issue " it is not displaying the URL div next to the first Status div and so fourth. The URL div displays last," I recommend the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="textboxStatus">
  </div>
  <div class="textboxURL">
  </div>
</div>
```

Apply `float: left;` to both `textboxStatus` and `textboxURL`.  I understand, this is dynamically generated, but instead, why not AJAX to fetch the content and then simply fill it?

You can easily use AJAX with webforms like so:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: this answer makes a ton of assumptions about the question, but is generally correct for what it proposes. floating both of your content divs to the left should work, as long as your parent container is wide enough to contain both.

Comment: Answers that are "generally correct" are "generally upvoted" :)

Comment: AJAX is great and was used originally. This product is to observe updates to software as they are pushed out. C# and ASP.NET allow for a more dynamic application.

Answer (score 1):

In your ".textboxStatus" css-class you have defined a "float:left" and are clearing the float at the same time with "clear:left".

Remove both attributes and in ".textboxURL" replace "float:right" with "float:left" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

first we will define the main div or body in which other will be contained for that div the style will be

```
  #maindiv{
          width: 100%;
          font-size: 12px;
          overflow: hidden;
          background: #ccc
    }
```

in your case it will be "container"

now when you are adding the divs as

then first div style will be

```
         #leftdiv {
                 float: left; 
                 width: 33%;
                 background-color: #bbb;
          }
```

after that set the width of each div and put the width to the style of that d

```
    #nextdiv { 
             float: left;
              background-color: #eee;
             width: 33%;
      }
```

and so on..

Comment: These DIVs are being dynamically created as log files are created. Styling each DIV does not work in this situation. Please read the question and look over the code examples before writing answers that don't help the solution.

Comment: in asp:panel you can give it maindiv style and when ever you add some div at run time at the div with the style above ..it will work..its just an idea i tried to explain you ..putting div's side by side is achive by giving them styles

Comment: have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krv9w/) hope this will give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a `<TABLE>` with one line `<TR>` and multiple columns `<td>` instead of generating an Asp.net `Gridview` control by Literal controls.

Remember to write Html tags when you use Literal controls

Example of final html:

```
<Table>
<tr>
<td>First div inside</td>
<td>Second div inside</td>
...
</tr>
</Table>
```

Comment: putting in tables is not the actual solution..its not a w3c standards